# How to separate a row into multiple rows with same values using mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I separate a row into multiple rows with same value using MYSQL?

For example:

I have the following cell TeethID lets say it contains the following

```
UL1 + UL2 + UL3, Jack
```

I want to separate it into multiple rows with same value of the other cells

```
UL1, Jack
UL2, Jack
UL3, Jack
```

Comment: It seems to me a database redesign would be the correct answer. Concatenating data into an _anything seperated list_ in a single column is a bad idea and now you know why. Imagine you were allowing a user to analyse this data using a simple query tool. This data would be totally impossible for them to make any use of

Comment: you can joining itselft 3 times